# Update Oracle Erro

Tags: oracle

Necessito de fazer um Update no oracle, duas tabelas relacionadas com o mesmo campos, executei o comando a baixo, e deu o seguinte resultado.

```
UPDATE  SAC_RV_DIVIDENDO,SAC_RV_DIVIDENDO_QTD_POS SET DT_EX='20190110' WHERE ID=53136
```

> Erro : ORA-00971: missing SET keyword

Answer (score 2):

O Oracle não suporta update simultâneo de 2 tabelas, seria necessário ou realizar 2 transações ou criar uma procedure que realize esse procedimento para você:

```
UPDATE SAC_RV_DIVIDENDO         SET DT_EX = '20190110' WHERE ID = 53136;
UPDATE SAC_RV_DIVIDENDO_QTD_POS SET DT_EX = '20190110' WHERE ID = 53136;
COMMIT;
```

Ou

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UPDATE_SAC_RV_DIVIDENDO(P_DT_EX IN VARCHAR2,
                                         P_ID    IN NUMBER) IS
BEGIN

  UPDATE SAC_RV_DIVIDENDO         SET DT_EX = P_DT_EX WHERE ID = P_ID;
  UPDATE SAC_RV_DIVIDENDO_QTD_POS SET DT_EX = P_DT_EX WHERE ID = P_ID;
  COMMIT;

END;
```

Answer (score 1):

Não acredito que Oracle ofereça suporte a múltiplas operações de *update* em um *statement* único. A solução seria encapsular as duas operações em uma transação:

```
START TRANSACTION;
UPDATE SAC_RV_DIVIDENDO         SET DT_EX='20190110' WHERE ID=53136;
UPDATE SAC_RV_DIVIDENDO_QTD_POS SET DT_EX='20190110' WHERE ID=53136;
COMMIT;
```